# Copying from mount share drive to local folder through script

Tags: 12.10, bash, mount, smb, rm

This is my first time trying to work with Linux Scripts so this may be something obvious.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Remove all contents from local folder - rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
2. Copy files from a shared windows network drive - cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/

So from my understanding my command should look like this

```
  rm /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
  cp smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

But anytime I try and run either of the above commands I get the following error:

```
  "rm: cannot remove `/home/user/Documents/Exercise/': Is a directory"
  "cp: cannot stat `smb://server/arc/Exercise%20Files/Word/': No such file or directory"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards,

M

EDIT:

I now have the `rm` function working yet am still troubled by the `cp` function. To ensure it is not an issue with the spaces in the folder names I have renamed the folders on the share so it now reads:
`//server/Arc/ExerciseFiles/*`

I have mounted the folder so I (assume) no longer need the `smb://`. It currently reads:
`cp -rfv /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/ExerciseFiles/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/`

M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No your commands should look like following

```
  rm -rfv /home/user/Documents/Exercise/*
```

because folder Exercise can have subdirectories

and in case of a samba share first you have to mount it locally

i.e.

```
mount -t smbfs smb://"server/arc/Exercise Files/Word/" /mnt
```

and then do

```
 cp /mnt /home/user/Documents/Exercise/
```

Comment: if there are blank spaces in your directory names I feel they probably are causing the problem so you can do some thing like quoting the names in double quotes ""

Comment: OP updated. `rm` command resolved thankyou. Still issues with `cp`.

Comment: can you post exactly what are the error messages and what are the commands you execute for cp http://www.linuxnix.com/2009/09/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux.html

Comment: sudo apt-get install smbfs
This will install the samba filesystem package on your system, simply re-run the mount command when you’ve got this package http://www.sirnet.co.uk/archives/114

Comment: I think it must have been the %20 in the originals. I restarted the machine and used the exact same command and it worked!

Comment: the following command worked - `cp -rfv /home/user/Documents/ExerciseShare/ExerciseFiles/Word/ /home/user/Documents/Exercise/`

thankyou for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the "minus r" flag or `-r`

`rm -r`

and

`cp -r`

This will copy or delete recursively into folders or files within files.